# Writing Program to Analyze File

Tags: c++

I am working on a code that analyzes an input file with an unknown number of lines. Each line is in a format that is "country, city, City, state, population, latitude, longitude". I am currently getting an error where my code sets smallest and largest populations. The error says "the left operand must be an lvalue". I tried looking this up but could not find an answer.

```
#include "city.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using std::string;
using std::ifstream;
using std::istream;
using std::ostream;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::getline;

void readLineOfData( istream& in, ostream& out, string &country,  string &city, string &city2, 
    string &state, int &pop, string &lat, string &longi);

void output( ostream& out, string country, string city, string city2,
    string state, int pop, string lat, string longi );

void cities( istream& in, ostream& out )
{
    ifstream ("cities.txt");
    string country, city, city2, state, lat, longi;
    int pop;
    readLineOfData(in, country, city, city2, state, pop, lat, longi);
    while(!in.fail())
    {

        output( cout, country, city, city2, state, pop, lat, longi );


        readLineOfData(in, country, city, city2, state, pop, lat, longi);
    }
    return;
}

void readLineOfData( istream& in, string &country,  string &city, string &city2, 
    string &state, int &pop, string &lat, string &longi)
{
    getline( in, country, ',');
    getline( in, city, ',');
    getline( in, city2, ',');
    getline( in, state, ',');
    in >> pop;
    in.ignore( 200, ',' );
    getline( in, lat, ',');
    getline( in, longi, '\n' );

}

void output( istream& in, ostream& out, string country, string city, string city2,
    string state, int pop, string lat, string longi )
{
    int smallestPop = 0;
    int largestPop = 0;
    string smallestCity;
    string largestCity;

    cout << country << endl;
    cout << city << endl;
    cout << city2 << endl;
    cout << state << endl;
    cout << pop << endl;
    cout << lat << endl;
    cout << longi << endl;

        if (pop < smallestPop || smallestPop == 0)
        {
            smallestPop = pop;
            smallestCity = city;
        }

        if (pop > largestPop || largestPop == 0)
        {
            largestPop = pop;
            largestCity = city;
        }

        out << "Smallest City: " << smallestCity << endl;
        out << "Population: " << smallestPop << endl;
        out << endl;
        out << "Largest City: " << largestCity << endl;
        out << "Largest Population: " << largestPop << endl;

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you put a comment on the two lines this error occurs, you'd have multiple answers by now. It's blindingly easy to spot once the line is highlighted compared to before. Those two are `if (pop < smallestPop || smallestPop = 0)` and `if (pop > largestPop || largestPop = 0)`. Also, just throwing it out there, GCC 4.8.0 puts a caret under the single equals sign and Clang 3.2 does the same, but underlines everything inside the if conditions before it with tildes. How cool is that for spotting the error?

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: You should keep the question as it was when answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `=` instead of `==` in several expressions:

```
if (pop < smallestPop || smallestPop = 0)
```

and:

```
if (pop > largestPop || largestPop = 0)
```

so you are doing an assignment instead of a comparison. We are seeing this error due to [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). Since both `<` and `||` have higher precedence than `=` in the first case we end up with:

```
((pop > smallestPop) || smallestPop) = 0
```

Which is assigning to a `lvalue`. If on the other hand you had this:

```
 if ( pop < smallestPop || (smallestPop = 0) )
```

The program would have compiled fine since the parenthesis would have caused the assignment to take place first. A simple way to avoid these types of problems as mentioned in the comments is to put the constant on the left. Although I like this solution a lot of developers balk at this non-traditional notation.

Comment: Thanks, this was the error.

Comment: To avoid this error put the constant on the left and it gives an error, 0=smallestPop is an error and the compiler will tell you.

Answer (score 0):

A quick guess, from looking at the code.  A common situation I've seen that reports "the left operand must be an lvalue", is when you accidentally use the "=" (assignment) operator when trying to compare for equality ("==" in C++ and many other languages).